# Stripe cards elements keep refreshing when I type

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I use two components for my checkout flow. I integrated Stripe card elements but whenever I type a card number, it refreshes at least 3 times before it stops and when I submit my data it doesn't seem to be well capture by my headless commerce. [I followed this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/card-element)

**When I submit this error shows**:

```
v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element.
          Please make sure the Element you are attempting to use is still mounted.
at et (v3:1:94950)
at e._handleMessage (v3:1:103953)
at e._handleMessage (v3:1:74083)
at v3:1:101904
```

This is my **PaymentOptions** component - level 3 (inside UserPayment component):

```
//Required
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import * as ga from '../../../lib/ga/index.js';
import { uid } from 'uid';
import CheckoutForm from './Checkout_Form_Custom';

//Styles
import { Flex, Box } from 'reflexbox';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { LoaderInBlue, PaypalButton, CustomCardButton } from 'components/GlobalStyles/Buttons';
import { SimpleErrorMessage } from 'components/GlobalStyles/Errors'

//Context
import EcommerceContext from '../../../context/EcommerceContext';

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
const stripePromise = loadStripe(publicRuntimeConfig.STRIPE_PK_TEST);

function PaymentOptions({formData, token, cartItems}){

    const router = useRouter();

    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState('');
    const [isStripe, setIsStripe] = useState(false);
    const [isPaypal, setIsPaypal] = useState(false);
    
    // Add auth context
    const { error, buttonProcessing } = useContext(EcommerceContext)

    const handleStripeButton = async (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsStripe(true);
         
        const generateNewTransactionId = uid()
        const totalPrice = cartItems && cartItems.length > 0 && cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.unitPrice * c.quantity, 0); 
    }

    const handlePaypalButton = async (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsStripe(false);
    }

    return( 
        <PaymentOptionsStyled className="payment-options">
            {buttonProcessing &&  
            /** if something is loading, show the loading icon**/
                <Flex justifyContent="center">
                    <LoaderInBlue />
                </Flex>
            }

            {error && <SimpleErrorMessage />}

            { 
                !isStripe && !isPaypal && 
                /** if no payment is selected, show payment buttons **/
                <>
                    <Flex justifyContent="center" className="card-option payment-option">
                        <CustomCardButton 
                            handleStripeButton={handleStripeButton} 
                        />
                    </Flex>

                    <Flex justifyContent="center" className="paypal-option payment-option">
                        <PaypalButton
                            handlePaypalButton={handlePaypalButton} 
                            formData={formData} 
                            cartItems={cartItems}
                        />
                    </Flex>
                </>
            }

            { 
                isStripe &&
                /**** if card payment is selected, show show Stripe Elements */
                <Box className='center-box'>
                    <Flex justifyContent="center">
                        <Elements /*options={options}*/ stripe={stripePromise}>
                            <CheckoutForm token={token} />
                        </Elements>
                    </Flex>
                    <Flex my={20}>
                        <Box as="button" onClick={()=> setIsStripe(false)}>
                            {'Retour'}
                        </Box>
                    </Flex>
                </Box>
            }
        </PaymentOptionsStyled>
    )
}

const PaymentOptionsStyled = styled.div`   
 ...
`

export default PaymentOptions
```

This is my **CheckoutForm** component - last level (inside PaymentOptions component):

```
//Required
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import swell from 'swell-js';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { 
    useStripe, 
    useElements, 
    CardElement 
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { success } from 'components/Utils/pageUrls';
import {
    submitOrder
} from '../../../context/CommerceServices';
import {
    newIntent
} from 'components/Utils/apis';

//Styles
import { Flex, Box } from 'reflexbox';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import Checkmark  from 'components/GlobalStyles/Animations/Checkmark';
import { LoaderInBlue, PayOrder, WaitingForPayment, SubmitPaymentButton } from 'components/GlobalStyles/Buttons';

//SEO & Cookies
import { setCookie, parseCookies, destroyCookie } from 'nookies';

//Contexts
import EcommerceContext from '../../../context/EcommerceContext';

const { API_URL } = process.env;


function CheckoutForm({formData, token, getPaymentIntentId}){

    //Commerce context
    const {
        cartItems,
        cart,
        errorBeforePayment,
        setErrorBeforePayment,
        paymentIntent,
        setPaymentIntent,
    } = useContext(EcommerceContext);

    //Defines states
    const router = useRouter();
    const [isData, setIsData] = useState(false);
    const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [tokenized, setTokenized] = useState(null);
    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState('');
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [newOrderId, setNewOrderId] = useState('');
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState('');
    const elements = useElements();
    const stripe = useStripe();

    //Fetch stripe paymentIntent
    useEffect(async(ctx) => {

        //Cart informations
        const intentData = {
            cartItems, 
            cart
        }

        //if user is logged in, fetch payment intent
        if(token){
            // Create paymentIntent as soon as the page loads
            paymentIntent = await fetch(`${API_URL}${newIntent}`, {   
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({intentData}),
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                //console.log('res payment:', res)
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log('data payment:', data)
                if(data.info && data.info.clientSecret){
                    setClientSecret(data.info.clientSecret);
                    setPaymentIntent(data.info.newId);
                    setIsData(true)
                }else{
                    setIsData(false)
                }
                
                if(data.info && data.info.newId){
                    setCookie(ctx, 'paymentIntentId', data.info.newId)
                }

                if(data.error){
                    setErrorBeforePayment(true)
                    
                }
            });
        }else{
            return
        }

    }, []);

    //Get form
    const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
 
    //Tokenize card details with Swell
    form && form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('adding listener');
        console.log('form', form)
        
        //raise flag!
        setProcessing(true);
        
        console.log('before tokenize');
        const tokenize = swell.payment.tokenize({
            card: {
                onError: (err) => {
                    //inform the customer there was an error
                    console.log('error tokenizing:', err);
                },
                onSuccess: () => {
                    //submit the form
                    console.log('succes tokenizing:', );
                    setTokenized(true);
                    if(tokenized){
                        console.log('tokenized so submit:', tokenized)
                        form.submit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        console.log('end listener');
        setProcessing(false);
    });

    
    //Submit payment to Stripe and handle error
    const handleSubmit = async ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();

        //raise flag!
        setProcessing(true);

        console.log('in submit func')

        if(clientSecret && tokenized){
            //if client secret is received, submit form
            console.log('submiting payment to stripe')
            const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                    card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
                }
            });
            console.log('end payload:')

            if (payload && payload.error) {
                setError(`Payment failed ${payload.error.message}`);
                setProcessing(false);
            } else {
                console.log('succeed !:', payload)
                setError(null);
                setProcessing(false);
                
                //const submitOrder = await swell.cart.submitOrder()
                
                setSucceeded(true);
                destroyCookie(null, 'paymentIntentId');
            }
        }else{
            //if tokenization was unsuccessful
            console.log('not tokenized so...bye!')
            return
        }
    };

    //handle payment success
    /*if(succeeded) return (
        <>
            <CheckoutFormStyled>
                <Flex flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center">
                    <p className=" checkout-success center">Paiement réussi!</p>
                    <Checkmark />
                </Flex>
            </CheckoutFormStyled>
            {setTimeout(()=> router.push(success + '?orderId=' + `${newOrderId}&si=${successId}` ), 2000)}
        </>
    )*/

    //Render Stripe Card Element
    const customCardElement = swell && swell.payment.createElements({
        card: {
            
            elementId: '#card-element-id', // default: #card-element
            options: {
                style: {
                    base: {
                        //iconColor: '#c4f0ff',
                        fontWeight: 500,
                        fontFamily: 'Ideal Sans, system-ui, sans-serif',
                        fontSize: "16px",
                    },
                },
            },
            onChange: event => {
                // optional, called when the Element value changes
                // Listen for changes in the CardElement
                // and display any errors as the customer types their card details
                //event.preventDefault();

                setDisabled(event.empty);
                setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
                console.log('changing field !', event)
            },
            onSuccess: result => {
                // optional, called on card payment success
                console.log('result !');
            },
            onError: error => {
                // optional, called on card payment error
                console.log('error !');
                setError(`Payment failed`);
                setProcessing(false);
            }
        }
    });

    
    return(
        <CheckoutFormStyled>
            {
                <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={(ev) => handleSubmit(ev)}>
                    
                    {
                        !isData &&
                        /** if there is no clientSecret yet, show the loading icon **/
                        <Flex justifyContent="center"><LoaderInBlue /></Flex>
                    }
                    
                    {
                        isData &&
                        /** When the clientSecret is ready, show Stripe CardElement and payment button**/
                        <>
                            <CardElement id="card-element-id"/>
                            <button as="button" className="ck-button order payment order-form-square"
                                disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}
                                type="submit"
                            >   
                                <Flex justifyContent='center' my={10}>
                                    { processing ?  
                                        <WaitingForPayment /> 
                                            : 
                                        <PayOrder className="order-button-content"/>
                                    }
                                </Flex>
                            </button>
                        </>
                        
                    }
                        
                    
                        {/* Show any error that happens when processing the payment */}
                        {error && 
                            <Box as="div" className="card-error" role="alert">
                                {error}
                            </Box>
                        }

                        {/* Show a success message upon completion */}
                        <Box as ="p" className={succeeded ? "result-message" : "result-message hidden"}>
                            Payé avec succès ! see result in your
                            <Box as="a"
                                href={`https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments`}
                            >
                                {" "}
                                Stripe dashboard.
                            </Box> Refresh the page to pay again.
                        </Box>
                </form>
            }

            {errorBeforePayment &&

                <Box>Une erreur est survenue. Veuillez réessayer ou contacter Famous in Vogue.</Box>
            }
        </CheckoutFormStyled>
    )

}

const CheckoutFormStyled = styled.div`
 ...
`

export default CheckoutForm
```

and lastly, this is my **MultiStep** component - level 1 (parent) UserPayment is level 2:

```
//Required
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { useForm, useStep } from 'react-hooks-helper';
import { UserIdentity, UserIdentityReview } from './Steps/User_Identity_Custom';
import { UserPaymentInactive, UserPayment } from './Steps/User_Payment_Custom';
import OrderSummary from 'components/Ecommerce/Order/Summary';

//Styles
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import {  Flex, Box } from 'reflexbox';

//contexts
import BreakPointContext from '../../../context/BreakPointContext';

const steps = [
    { id: 'détails de facturation'},
    { id: 'payment'},
];

function MultiStep ({cartItems, cart, token, auth_user, getPaymentIntentId, saveCartChanges}) {

    const defaultData = {
    firstnameInput: auth_user.myAddress && auth_user.myAddress.firstname,
    lastnameInput: auth_user.myAddress && auth_user.myAddress.lastname,
    emailInput: auth_user.myAddress && auth_user.email,
    postcodeInput: '',
    streetInput: '',
    cityInput: '',
    countryInput: ''
};

    const { isBreakpoint } = useContext(BreakPointContext); 
    const [formData, setForm] = useForm(defaultData);
    const {step, navigation} = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0,
    });

    const props = { formData, setForm, navigation };
    
    if(isBreakpoint){
        //if mobile
        switch(step.id){
            case 'détails de facturation':
                return( 
                
                    <CheckoutStyled >
                        <Flex className="checkout">
                            <Box clasName="order-summary checkout-step" width={isBreakpoint ? 1/1 : 1.5/3} mx={isBreakpoint ? 0 : 20}>
                                <OrderSummary {...props} cartItems={cartItems} />
                            </Box>
                            <Box clasName="checkout-steps" width={ isBreakpoint ? 1/1 : 2/3}>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserIdentity {...props} auth_user={auth_user} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart}/>
                                </Box>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserPaymentInactive {...props} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart}/>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                        </Flex>
                    </CheckoutStyled>
                )
            case 'payment':
                return( 
                
                    <CheckoutStyled>
                        <Flex className="checkout">
                            <Box clasName="order-summary" width={isBreakpoint ? 1/1 : 1.5/3} mx={isBreakpoint ? 0 : 20}>
                                <OrderSummary {...props} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart} saveCartChanges={saveCartChanges}/>
                            </Box>
                            <Box clasName="checkout-steps" width={ isBreakpoint ? 1/1 : 2/3}>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserIdentityReview {...props} auth_user={auth_user}/>
                                </Box>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserPayment {...props} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart} token={token} getPaymentIntentId={getPaymentIntentId} />
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                            
                        </Flex>
                    </CheckoutStyled>
                    
                )
        }
    }else{
        //if desktop
        switch(step.id){
            case 'détails de facturation':
                return( 
                
                    <CheckoutStyled>
                        <Flex className="checkout">
                            <Box clasName="checkout-steps" width={ isBreakpoint ? 1/1 : 2/3}>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserIdentity {...props} auth_user={auth_user} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart}/>
                                </Box>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserPaymentInactive {...props} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart}/>
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                            <Box clasName="order-summary checkout-step" width={isBreakpoint ? 1/1 : 1.5/3} mx={isBreakpoint ? 0 : 20}>
                                <OrderSummary {...props} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart}/>
                            </Box>
                        </Flex>
                    </CheckoutStyled>
                )
            case 'payment':
                return( 
                
                    <CheckoutStyled>
                        <Flex className="checkout">
                            <Box clasName="checkout-steps" width={2/3}>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserIdentityReview {...props} auth_user={auth_user}/>
                                </Box>
                                <Box clasName="checkout-step" my={20}>
                                    <UserPayment {...props} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart} token={token} getPaymentIntentId={getPaymentIntentId} />
                                </Box>
                            </Box>
                            <Box clasName="order-summary" width={1.5/3}>
                                <OrderSummary {...props} cartItems={cartItems} cart={cart} saveCartChanges={saveCartChanges} />
                            </Box>
                        </Flex>
                    </CheckoutStyled>
                )
        }

    }
}

const CheckoutStyled = styled.div`
  ...
`
export default MultiStep
```

Comment: We need more than the return.  You're mounting a ton of components based on state values where we can't see the logic.  Consider adding that in and paring down the code to be as minimal as possible.

Comment: Also please share the details of your `CheckoutForm` component.

Comment: @PsiKai I added more details.

Comment: Sorry @BrendanMoore I just added the ChekoutForm details

Comment: Oh, this is very complex. You need to break this down into pieces you can review individually. Somewhere your React component logic is causing the CardElement to unmount and remount. I'd start by adding logging to each functional competent + effect and event handler. Figure out what is running unexpectedly then investigate why. Why do you have handleSubmit and a manual submit event listener?

Comment: Yeah I decided to do as you said. For now, It seems like the multiple useState are causing this. handleSubmit is use to transmit the form to Stripe. The manual submit is used to register the card details before submitting. I just followed Swell.js instructions

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the useStates from CheckoutForm and the card payment form stopped refreshing when typing. I still have one error to fixed so my card details can be captured !
Thank you for your input.